# How does sending my public key to GitHub allow them to verify who I am?

Tags: github, public-key-encryption, ssh-keys

When connecting to GitHub using HTTPS they will obviously want to verify me by asking for my password.  I enter my password, it checks out, and then they allow me to write to my repo.

With SSH keys setup, I create a public_key and a private_key pair.  The way I understand it, the public_key I use to encrypt and the private_key I used to decrypt.

I then keep the private_key on my machine and share it with no one.  I then go to GitHub and paste in my public_key.

How do they then authorize me?  Do they use my public_key to encrypt a message and then wait for me to send back the decrypted messsage?  If they get back the message decrypted properly, then they know its me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do they use my public_key to encrypt a message and then wait for me to send back the decrypted message?

Rather the other way around. You (your local SSH client) encrypt something using your private key. And if they are able to decrypt it using the public key you gave them, it must be you.

Obviously this is a very simplified explanation.

For details, see

- [How does asymmetric encryption work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/292)
- [How does ssh public key authentication work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/23227/43677)